# Yesod Scaffolding Project: Stack Build automatic removal of my package in cabal file

Tags: haskell, yesod

In the project cabal file, I have added a package.
But whenever I run `stack build` or `stack exec -- yesod devel`, the package got removed from cabal automatically.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't edit `.cabal` file while using `hpack`. The Yesod scaffolding uses stack with hpack. hpack generates your .cabal file by reading the `package.yaml` file. Add your package to the `dependencies` section in the package.yaml file, it then gets added to .cabal file during build.